# It has a sense to says that a field is an UFD ? (unique factorization domain)

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

It has a sense to says that a field is an UFD ? (unique factorization domain) For example is $\mathbb Q$ a UFD ? I would say no since for me in a field irreducible element has no sense. Indeed, let $K$ a field. Then $K$ the only ideals are $(1)$ and $(0)$, therefore, the only irreducible are $1$ and $0$.

Am I right ?

Comment: Btw, your question title says "Is a field a UFD", to which Henno has answered "yes". But the last sentence of your question is "Am I right [in saying that $\mathbb{Q}$ is *not* a field]?", to which the answer is "no" by the usual definitions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), yes.

Every $x \in K$ with $x \neq 0$ is a unit. There are no irreducible elements. So the "factorisation" of $x$ is just $x$ (a unit, empty product of irreducibles), and this is clearly unique in the sense as mentioned on the wiki page.

They also explicitly mention the inclusion of fields into UFD's.

Comment: In fact by the wikipedia definition you needn't even say that the "factorisation" of $x$ is just $x$ or worry about whether that's unique or not. The condition for UFD defined on that page is "every non-zero non-unit element has a certain property". There are no non-zero non-unit elements in a field (the definition of "unit" is provided in the wikipedia page for Commutative Ring, as "possessing an inverse"). So the condition is vacuously met, we don't even have to consider what the property is.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that the definition in the Definition section is subtly different from the definition in the opening paragraph, in that it handles the case of units in different words (but equivalently in the long run). Good 'ol wikipedia ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, I tried to handle the definition in the definition section.

Comment: Yep, so in "a product (an empty product if x is a unit) of irreducible elements $p_i$ of R and a unit u", then the product is empty and we choose $x$ to be $u$.